# Kibana - Get a list of all indices

Tags: elasticsearch, indices, kibana

I have ElasticSearch installed on a server and Kibana 3.0 installed on another machine. Is there any way to get a list of all the indices on the ElasticSearch server to show up on Kibana? Just like how ElasticSearch-Head displays it. Maybe in a new dashboard on Kibana that shows all the indices?

Answer (score 22):

you can get list of all indices  with

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

Answer (score 8):

First, you have to open your kibana.yml file and add this line

```
elasticsearch.url: "http://{IP of machine}:9200"
```

Then, restart your kibana. It will connect to elasticsearch of that machine

To get all indices run this

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set your Kibana dashboard configuration to _all in index settings (the default for the sample dashboard at #/dashboard/file/guided.json), all indices will be queried.

From there, you can add a terms panel for the _index field. That will list the top indices in terms of number of documents that they contain.